# How can I get an XML export of my 1K+ posts WordPress instance?

Tags: php, export, xml

I'd like to export my database to XML because the import script to my new blog already supports getting data from that.  A database backup or wordpress clone is not that useful in this case.  The problem is that using the builtin export button times out after 90 seconds.  I have ssh access to the server and am not afraid to use it :)

I don't really know php but I can muddle around with help.  Given [Problem: Create a cron job to export posts to a WordPress XML file on server](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10672/problem-create-a-cron-job-to-export-posts-to-a-wordpress-xml-file-on-server) I think that the export_wp function might be what I want, I just don't know what to do with that...

Comment: It would really be much easier to just configure PHP not to time out after 90 seconds. Or upgrade your db server to get the job done in 90 seconds. Depending on where you're hosting it, both things can be much easier than what you're proposing.

Comment: Agreed with @tbuteler. If you have ssh access, reconfigure PHP and/or MySQL to have longer timeouts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You guys give up too easily :)

This worked for me:

```
<?php
require(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/wp-load.php');
require(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php');
require('includes/export.php');

ob_start();
export_wp();
$xml = ob_get_clean();

file_put_contents('out.xml', $xml);
echo "done"
?>
```

Comment: This gives me a 502 error on my WP Engine site. Any suggestions?