# Why do I get undefined function export_wp()?

Tags: functions, export, filesystem

I'm trying to create a function in `functions.php` or a plugin to generate an export via a cronjob, similar to how Chris_O did [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10672/problem-create-a-cron-job-to-export-posts-to-a-wordpress-xml-file-on-server). However it seems that I can't call `export_wp()`, I keep getting:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function export_wp() in wherever-I-call-it-from.php on line 686
```

Can someone tell me how to call that function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function lives in `wp-admin/includes/export.php` and is only included on the export admin page (see [source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.5.1/wp-admin/export.php#L16)).

If you want to use it on other pages, you'll have to include it manually:

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/export.php' );
```